# How to update datetime everysecond in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, timeout

this is my first attempt at javascript and i have been trying to setup a live clock on my site, and i got the clock to show the time in the way that i want, but i cant get it to autoupdate every second with timeout command. What am i doing wrong here?

ps. if someone has a good idea how to change the time to UTC time, that would aswell be much appreciated, im still working on that my self though.

thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script> 
var date=new Date();
var format = "YYYY-MMM-DD DDD";
document.write(dateConvert(date,format));

function dateConvert(dateobj,format){
 var year = dateobj.getFullYear();
 var month= ("0" + (dateobj.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2);
 var date = ("0" + dateobj.getDate()).slice(-2);
 var hours = ("0" + dateobj.getHours()).slice(-2);
 var minutes = ("0" + dateobj.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
 var seconds = ("0" + dateobj.getSeconds()).slice(-2);
 var day = dateobj.getDay();
 var months = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12"];
 var converted_date = "";

switch(format){
 case "YYYY-MM-DD":
  converted_date = year + "-" + month + "-" + date;
  break;
case "YYYY-MMM-DD DDD":
  converted_date = year + "-" + months[parseInt(month)-1] + "-" + date
  + " " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
  break;
}
return converted_date;
}
</script>
</head>
    <body onload="dataConvert()",timeout(dateConverter,1000)>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First rule of thumb. Don't use `document.write()`.

Comment: set the javascript function `setInterval`

Comment: what is `timeout`?

Comment: A lot is wrong with this code. No such thing as timeout. The JS function is called setTimeout(). Even with setTimeout it will not print anything because there is only one document.write in the beginning. If you move the document.write inside the dateConvert() function then it will print the date again n again on a new line. You need a div or some placeholder to display time and update the content with setTimeout or setInterval()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there is this nice javascript function called setInterval (as already said by sheplu.

So you can pretty much remove the onload object and the timeout and use the setInterval.

Which would look like this:

```
setInterval(function(){
  var date = new Date();
  var format = "YYYY-MMM-DD DDD";
  dateConvert(date,format)
}, 1000);
```

Of course you would have to do some fine tuning like the var format directly in the interval is not the best since it doesn't change.

Look at the script here: https://jsfiddle.net/cv8wLgux/

Sites used : [MozillaDev](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) , [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

Answer (score 1):

I used the moment.js library to simplify the request. The clock is set on an interval to update every 1000ms (1 second).

```
setInterval(function(){
  document.getElementById("clock").innerText = moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');  
},1000)
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/eDKBOJUsE1a8aYTzax7g?p=preview

```
setInterval(function(){
  document.getElementById("clock").innerText = moment.utc().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
},1000)
```

Comment: Dont know how to use libraries yet, but will definetly look it up tomorrow and work it out and make the final version with this.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it the following way

```
function updateTimer() { "put your code to format the output here" }

setInterval("updateTimer()", 500)
```

I would have the interval timer fire every 1/2 second (or more often),
becausethe given time interval is only approximate.  If you use 1000 ms
the time between calls might be anywhere from 990 - 1010 ms (or wider)
and you might lose or duplicate the event on some seconds.

If you have it called more often, you can get the current time down to
the millisecond from a Date variable and decide what you want to do each time.

Answer (score 0):

Use the setInterval function.
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval

not sure about it, should try, but I think if you keep your page open, you could loose some seconde every hours/days. So you should time to time check the new time and update everything

Comment: yeah i dont want the whole page to refresh, just the datetime.

Comment: about the code ? yes, pretty much everything need to be done another way ! But just giving him the funciton to use to call something every X time ;)

here is the function with just the second, up to him to read it, try it and do stuff ! (sorry, just output the result in the console)

https://jsfiddle.net/k2sg8fe1/